# Does HSTS HTTP Strict-Transport-Security has to be sent with any response file?

Tags: http, http-headers

I have to add security measures to a website running a Tomcat 6 application server. One of it is adding the HTTP Strict-Transport-Policy Header. I did this by adding a filter which is in turn adding this header to any response. But there is static content served by apache webservers (in front of the application server), I have no access to. So my question is: Do I have to take care for this? Is it necessary to return this header with every served file (.css, .js, etc.)?  As far as I understand this header, it tells the browser "Hey, if you read this, access this domain via HTTPS only for the next ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSTS applies to the entire domain, so setting it in all of your responses should do the trick just fine.

Comment: Thats the point. It is not in all of my responses, only the ones where the application server is directly involved and so the filter is called. The question is: Is this insufficient?

Comment: Presumably no one's loading your JS/CSS/images without being on a page served by your application server already? If so, should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to send the header with every response. In [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797), section 6.1.1:

> The REQUIRED "max-age" directive specifies the number of seconds,
> after the reception of the STS header field, during which the UA
> regards the host (from whom the message was received) as a Known HSTS
> Host.

So the header is explicitly designed to be used for the entire domain, and cached. To protect your static assets that don't have this header, you *do* have to have the browser access a route that sends the header first, and then again before the max-age value expires.